# ng2-translate on tabTitle in Ionic 2 don't appear

Tags: angular, translation, ionic2

I am trying to use ng2-translate for an ion-tab, but the title doesn't appear ... I don't understand because I had already used a translation on another file and it worked!

This is my HTML code in my tabs.html:

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="{{'TEST' | translate}}" tabBadge="1" tabBadgeStyle="notif"></ion-tab>
```

And my code in tabs.ts

```
export class TabsPage {
   tab2Root : Page2;
}
constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
 translate.setDefaultLang('fr');
 translate.use('fr');
}
}
```

I have a fr.json file on my assets/translation folder. It works because I already use it.

I don't know what I have to do ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. My traduction appear on the page but a default style set the display of my span at "none". I had override this style to resolve my problem.

```
.tab-button-text {
     display: block !important
}
```

I changed this in my variable.scss file. 
I hope my answer can help someone.

Comment: Works, but should be `.tab-button-text`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and another solution is to leave a space before the translation. In your case, like this:

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle=" {{'TEST' | translate}}" tabBadge="1" tabBadgeStyle="notif"></ion-tab>
```

:)